# It's asking for the logShout console log so I input this but its not working

Tags: node.js

1) logShout(string) calls console.log() its one argument in all caps:
     ReferenceError: toUpperCase is not defined
      at logShout (file://index.html:11:15)
      at Context. (test/index-test.js:18:5)

```
return string.toUpperCase()
}
function whisper(string) {
return string.toLowerCase()
}

function logShout (string) {
console.log(toUpperCase);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you post seems has some syntax error. Please have a check. 
To quick answer `toUpperCase is not defined at logShout`, maybe you are calling `toUpperCase` on a non-string type of variable.